# How do I return one random external xml set of data on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

In my code below I can loop through my xml file, but I can't find a way to output a random set on page load for example: (Banana 4011).

I'm not familiar with xml and getting its contents with javascript.

// my code outputs ( BananaLemon )

// plu.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<doc>
  <item>
    <name>lemon</name>
    <code>4053</code>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>banana</name>
    <code>4011</code>
  </item>
</doc>
```

//javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
    url: "plu.xml" ,
    dataType: "xml" ,
    success: function(xml) {

    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );  
    //if single item
    var plu = $(xml).find('item').text();  
    //but if it's multible items then loop
    $(xml).find('name').each(function(){
     $("#item").append($(this).text());  
    }); 
    }       
});
});
```

// Any knowledge is greatly appreciated, and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need **$parseXML** and you can iterate directly on the parents: **item**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
    url: "1.xml" ,
    dataType: "xml" ,
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
            $("#item").append($('<p/>', {text: 'name: ' + $(this).find('name').text() +
            ' code: ' + $(this).find('code').text()}));
        });
    }
});
```

From your comment:

> Still curious how to return one random result set from the xml file

the code is:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
    url: "1.xml" ,
    dataType: "xml" ,
    success: function(xml) {
        var eles = $(xml).find('item');
        var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * eles.length);
        $("#item").append($('<p/>', {text: 'name: ' + eles.eq(rn).find('name').text() +
        ' code: ' + eles.eq(rn).find('code').text()}));
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks much better. Still curious how to return one random result set from the xml file.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for making it so simple.